# Mongodb: 'mongod' command not starting the local server

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have recently downloaded the mongodb ,, and try trying to run the mongod command and it just not running the local server , it throwing error repeatedly,
[output screen when I am running the 'mongod' command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH7ks.png)

I have almost tried all the possible way to solve it , but not getting resolved.
please help if anyone know the solution.

Comment: The "waiting for connections" at the bottom means there was no error and the server is now running.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551